# Assigning irregular points to a grid and assigning grid number as attribute

Tags: r, point, spatial-join, sorting

I have a large point data set that has irregular geometry (random sampling) that I want to bin in 2D XY space. I've attached a sketch below to illustrate what I mean. Apologies for hand drawing, hope no one minds.

So far I've been using the fishnet option in ArcGIS+QGIS and SAGA tool polygon attribute to points. However I have reached the workable file size limit for my shapefiles (>2GB). When attempting to use feature classes ArcGIS is incredibly slow at performing the required task, so I have been mostly focusing on SAGA for its speed.

It's been suggested to me by a colleague that I could use GMT's blockmean, blockmedian, blockmode programs. However I have limited experience in this but would be willing to learn IF it is the right direction

I can see the maths of all this as a matrix operation, but the problem I am having is with the large data size. My point files are >700mb in just XY coordinates (billions of points).

I am not looking for interpolation, just looking to assign the points a 'bin' reference in XY space.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

R would be a good place to do this, if you're willing to copy a little code. I think in general you are looking for a raster function, essentially. If you need it as a polygon, you can convert the raster to polygon when you're finished.

```
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
library(plyr)

# load your points
points <- readOGR("points.shp", "points")

# create a blank raster that has the same extent as the points layer
r <- raster(ext=extent(points))

# set the resolution of the raster to the size of the cell you want
res(r) <- 1000

# use the count function from the plyr package
re <- extract(r, y, fun='count')
```

R can handle the 700MB points layer, it shouldn't be too slow.

Comment: Going to give this a go in the next 2-3 hours, will get back on how things work out later tonight or tomorrow (UK time)